# WPF ''local' is an undeclared prefix

Tags: c#, wpf, local

I have a problem with a defined `local` alias; why is it not valid?

I have all of these classes which are not found.

Error list

```
Error   3   ''local' is an undeclared prefix. Line 1, position 2.' XML is not valid.    c:\..\SofiaCarRental.WPF\Views\AddEditWindow.xaml   1   2   SofiaCarRental.WPF
Error   5   The attachable property 'Resources' was not found in type 'Window'. c:\..\SofiaCarRental.WPF\Views\AddEditWindow.xaml   8   6   SofiaCarRental.WPF
Error   2   The name "NullableBooleanConverter" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:SofiaCarRental.WPF.Views".   c:\..\SofiaCarRental.WPF\Views\MainWindow.xaml  10  9   SofiaCarRental.WPF
Error   1   The namespace prefix "local" is not defined.    c:\..\SofiaCarRental.WPF\Views\AddEditWindow.xaml   1   1   SofiaCarRental.WPF
Error   4   The type 'local:BaseDialogWindow' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.  c:\..\SofiaCarRental.WPF\Views\AddEditWindow.xaml   1   2   SofiaCarRental.WPF
Error   8   The type 'local:EmptyStringConverter' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.  c:\..\SofiaCarRental.WPF\Views\AddEditWindow.xaml   11  10  SofiaCarRental.WPF
Error   6   The type 'local:NullableBooleanConverter' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.  c:\..\SofiaCarRental.WPF\Views\AddEditWindow.xaml   9   10  SofiaCarRental.WPF
Error   7   The type 'local:YearConverter' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built. c:\..\SofiaCarRental.WPF\Views\AddEditWindow.xaml   10  10  SofiaCarRental.WPF
```

Main Window (here I specified 'local')

```
<Window x:Class="SofiaCarRental.WPF.Views.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:local ="clr-namespace:SofiaCarRental.WPF.Views" 
    Title="Sofia Car Rental" 
    Height="720" Width="1280"
    MinHeight="720" MinWidth="1280">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:NullableBooleanConverter x:Key="booleanConverter" />
    <Style x:Key="checkBoxColStyle" TargetType="telerik:GridViewCell">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto">
   ...
</Grid></Window>
```

AddEditWindow

```
<local:BaseDialogWindow x:Class="SofiaCarRental.WPF.Views.AddEditWindow"
    xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="AddEditWindow" 
    Height="417" Width="383"
    Title="{Binding Path=Title}">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:NullableBooleanConverter x:Key="booleanConverter" />
    <local:YearConverter x:Key="yearConverter" />
    <local:EmptyStringConverter x:Key="emptyStringConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Margin="20,10,50,10">
   ...
</Grid></local:BaseDialogWindow>
```

BaseDialogWindow class:

```
namespace SofiaCarRental.WPF.Views
{
public class BaseDialogWindow : Window
{
    public BaseDialogWindow()
    {
        this.Owner = App.Current.MainWindow;
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        this.ResizeMode = System.Windows.ResizeMode.NoResize;
        this.WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
    }
}}
```

NullableBooleanConverter

```
namespace SofiaCarRental.WPF.Views{
public class NullableBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        object result = this.NullableBooleanToFalse(value);
        return result;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        object result = this.NullableBooleanToFalse(value);
        return result;
    }
    private object NullableBooleanToFalse(object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: Does the directory structure on the first error line seem correct? Not that it should matter but what if you put the telerik line below local? Also not that it should matter, but what if you created a project of "SofiaCarRentallWPF" (without the period) to see if it changes?

Comment: Telerik below local didn't help. SofiaCarRentalWPF name without the period also didn't change anything. The structure seems good, I did it exactly as it is in tutorial... I did tutorial from scratch two times and the same error apears...

Comment: 1. In your `AddEditWindow` xaml file, the prefix `local` is not declared. 2. Your `NullableBooleanConverter` is probably declared in a different namespace than `SofiaCarRental.WPF.Views`. Can you post its code (including the namespace declaration)?

Comment: "change the name of the opening tag from Window to local:BaseDialogWindow. This way the window will be actually be an instance of the class defined earlier - BaseDialogWindow" I thought that I can use 'local' declared in MainWindow.

Comment: @BeataK: No, you cannot. Each xaml file is a separate xml document and, as such, each must define its own namespaces.

Comment: I'm going from memory here BUT I think when I have encountered this and everything was correct regarding namespaces and such, it turned out to be a disconnect from Visual Studio and WPF. Jiggling the handle like rebuilding the solution, recreating the namespace (watching the intellisense) and removing, closing the editor and then adding it back in again seemed to help. Sometimes I have found that the editor does funny things sometimes. Other times what I thought was correct wasn't.

Comment: @MikeCheel Did you look at the code (or even the other comments) before making the claim that this is a VS error?

Comment: I didn't make a claim. I just said that sometimes the editor does weird things when everything is actually ok and to jiggle the handle. I have had that happen number of times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Error   3   ''local' is an undeclared prefix. Line 1, position 2.' XML is not valid.    c:..\SofiaCarRental.WPF\Views\AddEditWindow.xaml   1   2   SofiaCarRental.WPF

In the file `AddEditWindow.xaml`, the `local` prefix is not declared. XML namespace declarations work on a file-by-file basis. They are not inherited, and only ever active for the current file. If you want to use components from other namespaces in that file, you will have to add the declaration there too. You can see them like `using`s in code—whenever you want to use a type, you have to tell the compiler where to look for it first:

```
<local:BaseDialogWindow x:Class="SofiaCarRental.WPF.Views.AddEditWindow"
    …
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SofiaCarRental.WPF.Views"
    … >
```

---

> Error   5   The attachable property 'Resources' was not found in type 'Window'. c:..\SofiaCarRental.WPF\Views\AddEditWindow.xaml   8   6   SofiaCarRental.WPF

While `local:BaseDialogWindow` is a subtype of `Window`, this is still the type for this file. The compiler sees this when it looks at the XAML for this part:

```
<SomeType …>
    <OtherType.Property>…</OtherType.Property>
</SomeType>
```

And this is essentially equivalent to this:

```
<SomeType … OtherType.Property="…" />
```

Since `OtherType` is not the same as `SomeType`, this is an *attached property* in XAML. But `Window` does not have an attached property called `Resources`.

What you want to do instead is set the `Resources` property of your window instead. And your window type is `SomeType`, so you need to write it like this:

```
<SomeType …>
    <SomeType.Property>…</SomeType.Property>
</SomeType>
```

So in your case, you want to set your resources like this:

```
<local:BaseDialogWindow x:Class="SofiaCarRental.WPF.Views.AddEditWindow"
        … >
    <local:BaseDialogWindow.Resources>
        …
    </local:BaseDialogWindow.Resources>
    …
</local:BaseDialogWindow>
```

---

The remaining errors are all because you are using the `local:` prefix without declaring it first and the compiler not finding your types.

Comment: Thank you poke! I fixed the problem. This tutorial is not clear and contains mistakes. Now i understand better

Comment: ...and remember to rebuild or just play again if you still get errors, it made me loss a lot of time and just need to push play and errors were gone